# css flex-item default height issue

Tags: css, flexbox

i am learning CSS flex-box stuff and when i play around with it i have found a wired thing:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

.box1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
}

.box2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">
      <p class="text">I do not remember how and when I discovered her music, but when I heard her, I was moved by…</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box box2">
      <p class="text">I do not remember how and when I discovered her music, but when I heard her, I was moved by…</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box box3">
      <p class="text">I do not remember how and when I discovered her music, but when I heard her, I was moved by…</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

the wired thing is: i have set the height of box1 element to 500px only, but from the result, i saw the box2 got the same height as 500px default even i didn't set any height value on it. And then i changed the box2 height value as 300px and didn't give a fix height on box3:

```
    .box1{
        border: 2px solid red;
        width: 30%;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .box2{
        border: 2px solid blue;
        width: 40%;
        height:300px;
    }


    .box3{
     border: 2px solid blue;
     width:30%;
    }
```

this time from the result i found the height of box3 was 500px so my questions are:

1. after calling container as `display:flex`, is that the flex items with no pre-height set will inherit the other flex item with biggest hight value?
2. after calling container as `display:flex`, may i consider all its contained items will behave like `inline-block`elements?

Answer (score 0):

*1. After calling container as display:flex, is that the flex items with no pre-height set will inherit the other flex item with biggest height value?*

All items in row will take the largest height of them by default.

*2. After calling container as display:flex, may i consider all its contained items will behave like  inline-blockelements?*

Yes, you can use [`display: inline-flex`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) (find `inline-flex` value in this page for more info).